# Getting "Unable to get public no-arg constructor" When Using "logstash LogstashEncoder"

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, logstash, logback

I'm trying to configure a Spring Boot project to use `net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder` to format log output in JSON and provide the ability to use the `keyValue` method for adding custom fields to the output. I know there are other ways of doing it, but many of our current applications using an older version of Spring use this technique and it works well. In order to update those applications, we'd like to be able to use the same configuration.

The problem I'm having is that with the following `logstash.xml` file:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="json" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="json" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

I'm getting the following error when starting the app:

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder@4f659288 - Error occurred while dynamically loading jackson modules java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate5.Hibernate5Module Unable to get public no-arg constructor
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:328)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:216)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:344)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.lowes.oms.eor.services.order.Application.main(Application.java:33)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder@4f659288 - Error occurred while dynamically loading jackson modules java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate5.Hibernate5Module Unable to get public no-arg constructor
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:232)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:313)
    ... 23 more
```

If I look in `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate5.Hibernate5Module`, there is a public no-arg constructor.

**Relevant dependency versions:**

- Spring Boot*: 2.7.2
- Jackson*: 2.13.3 (managed by Spring Boot)
- Logback*: 1.2.11 (managed by Spring Boot)

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was an incompatibility between `logstash-logback-encoder` and `jackson-datatype-hibernate5`. Whenever I try to use the logstash encoder with `jackson-datatype-hibernate5` on the classpath, the error occurs. I've raised an issue in the logstash github repo here: https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder/issues/878